# Case Auto-Response Rules not matching the matching criteria which is updated from Process Builder

Tags: trigger, process-builder, case, email2case, case-auto-response

We have a requirement to implement email2case process in which we are adding to-address from Email Message object to Case object field.

For example if abc@a.com send an email to our email(email2case) address then email message process builder will update to address value in case object email. This is working fine.

Now the problem is we need to have case auto response rule on the same field which we got from email message object to case object but that is not matching the criteria.

Is there some solution for this to achieve it? I already tried apex trigger but no success yet.

Comment: This looks like an [Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) problem. The Case Auto-Response rules will fire when the Case is inserted; long before the email address is added to the parent Case custom field.

Comment: @cropredy I posted a very specific question with code and that works with one hard coded email but not with dynamic email https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/325562/emailmessage-object-access-in-case-trigger-after-insert